# Unable to read file from Azure Blob Storage mount from Databrick's Connect Apache Spark

Tags: azure, apache-spark, databricks, azure-databricks

I configured a databricks connect on Azure to run my spark programs on Azure cloud. For a dry run I tested a wordcount program. But the program is failing with following error.

"`Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist:`"

I am using Intellij to run the program. I have the necessary permissions to access the cluster. But I still I am getting this error.

The following program is a wrapper which takes in the parameters and publishes the results.

```
package com.spark.scala
import com.spark.scala.demo.{Argument, WordCount}
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

import com.databricks.dbutils_v1.DBUtilsHolder.dbutils

import scala.collection.mutable.Map

object Test {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val argumentMap: Map[String, String] = Argument.parseArgs(args)
    val spark = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .master("local")

      .getOrCreate()
    println(spark.range(100).count())


    val rawread = String.format("/mnt/%s", argumentMap.get("--raw-reads").get)
    val data = spark.sparkContext.textFile(rawread)

    print(data.count())

    val rawwrite = String.format("/dbfs/mnt/%s", argumentMap.get("--raw-write").get)
    WordCount.executeWordCount(spark, rawread, rawwrite);
    // The Spark code will execute on the Databricks cluster.
    spark.stop()
  }
}
```

The following code performs the wordcount logic:-

```
package com.spark.scala.demo


import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object WordCount{

  def executeWordCount(sparkSession:SparkSession, read: String, write: String)
  {
    println("starting word count process ")


    //val path = String.format("/mnt/%s", "tejatest\wordcount.txt")

    //Reading input file and creating rdd with no of partitions 5
    val bookRDD=sparkSession.sparkContext.textFile(read)

    //Regex to clean text
    val pat = """[^\w\s\$]"""
    val cleanBookRDD=bookRDD.map(line=>line.replaceAll(pat, ""))

    val wordsRDD=cleanBookRDD.flatMap(line=>line.split(" "))

    val wordMapRDD=wordsRDD.map(word=>(word->1))

    val wordCountMapRDD=wordMapRDD.reduceByKey(_+_)



    wordCountMapRDD.saveAsTextFile(write)



  }
}
```

I have written a mapper to map the paths given and I am passing the read and write locations through command line. My pom.xml is as follows: -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>ex-com.spark.scala</groupId>
    <artifactId>ex- demo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-mllib -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.25</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.clapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>grizzled-slf4j_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.25</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.databricks</groupId>
            <artifactId>dbutils-api_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


</project>
```

Comment: have you tried using the Service principal like this https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/azure/azure-datalake.html

Comment: @MaheshGupta Yes I tried the service principal to get access to mount and it was working fine.

Comment: so you want to access by Intellij then you need to add dependency using MAVEN or SBT.

Comment: @MaheshGupta I have added dependency using maven and I updated the post with the pom.xml I am using.

Comment: so how do you provide credential for accessing ADLS?

Comment: I am running this on the databricks connect so I gave the credentials related to that databricks in edit configurations tab. Apart from this I have not passed any credentials related to mount. Should I pass credentials related to the mount?

Comment: yes you need to give  access to Storage.